# How to display graphical information infinitely downward in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

Example:
[image]

I need to display more rows like this (in the direction of the red arrow), with more of those squares. Along with the squares I could also use other shapes of various colours, and the objects need to be placed in very specific coordinates. When I hover over any of those objects, it has to show a tooltip relevant to that object. The text shown, would be rendered as a graphical object, and not as text that can be selected with a mouse pointer. Basically, everything is fully graphically rendered.
As more data is generated, more rows will be added and it goes on infinitely. Obviously a scrollbar is needed.
So far, from libraries like Matplotlib, I've known only options of creating a graphical screen of fixed size. I considered [PyQt widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216927/pyqt-embedding-graphics-object-in-widget), but it doesn't seem to have the desired functionality.
I considered HTML (since adding new rows infinitely is easy) and JavaScript, but it's too cumbersome to export the data from Python and load and parse it in JavaScript.

Is there any way to do such a display in Python? Demonstrating one way of achieving this objective effectively would suffice.
Purpose: I'm creating this to visualize how certain foods and sleep loss lead to health issues. Displaying it like this allows me to see patterns across weeks or months. It's not just about plotting points and text, it's also about being able to dynamically update their color and size on clicking any of the graphical elements.

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to achieve this with Python with lots of libraries (including Qt). It can be done using standard widgets, with those squares carefully placed, or along with custom widget subclasses that paint their contents, or even using the [Graphics View framework](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html), which is possibly more ideal for such a purpose, but also requires a certain amount of knowledge/experience with that framework. In fact, there are *too* many possible ways to achieve this, which makes your question too broad, and SO isn't meant to provide answers for such questions.

Comment: StackOverflow has a vast number of answers which show different ways to do what people have asked. Even if there are various ways to achieve what I asked, all I need is one example. Thanks for pointing me to the graphics view framework.

Comment: I should probably rephrase. There are too many different and complex ways to achieve that. While SO encourages giving multiple solutions, if you don't limit the scope (the framework, the wider approach, etc.) then the question becomes too broad, especially because each approach has its own underlying complexity that cannot share a common implementation. Now, with your new edit, the question has become a bit more focused than it originally was, even if the question remains broad ("Is there any way to do such a display in Python").

Comment: See [ask]. Be specific and focus on a single problem. Also remove all the unnecessary information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a basic example, based on musicamante's suggestion.

```
import sys
import random
import string
import datetime
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QScrollArea, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer

class Constants:
    MAIN_WINDOW_WIDTH = 900
    MAIN_WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600
    TOOLTIP_DURATION_MSEC = 3000
    SHAPE_RECTANGLE = 'Rectangle'
    SHAPE_ELLIPSE = 'Ellipse'

class Markers(QWidget):
    colors = {}  # Class-level variable to store colors for each instance
    shapes = {}
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_color()
        self.color = Markers.colors[self]
        self.shapes = Markers.shapes[self]

    def init_color(self):
        if self not in Markers.colors:
            Markers.colors[self] = self.generate_random_color()        
            Markers.shapes[self] = self.generate_random_shape()    

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)        
        self.draw_random_shapes(painter)

    def draw_random_shapes(self, painter):
        colors = [QColor(255, 0, 0), QColor(0, 255, 0), QColor(0, 0, 255)]

        for _ in range(random.randint(1, 5)):
            painter.setBrush(self.color)
            x = 0; y = 0;
            if self.shapes == Constants.SHAPE_RECTANGLE:
                #width = random.randint(10, 40); height = random.randint(10, 40)
                width = 5; height = width
                painter.drawRect(x, y, width, height)
            elif self.shapes == Constants.SHAPE_ELLIPSE:
                radiusWidth = 5; radiusHeight = radiusWidth
                painter.drawEllipse(x, y, radiusWidth, radiusHeight)
        
    def generate_random_color(self):
        return QColor(random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255))
    
    def generate_random_shape(self):
        return random.choice([Constants.SHAPE_ELLIPSE, Constants.SHAPE_RECTANGLE])

class OneRowData(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, date, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.date = date
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        dateLabel = QLabel(self.date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))        
        layout.addWidget(dateLabel, Qt.AlignLeft)
        dots = Markers()
        toolstring = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=10))
        dots.setToolTip(toolstring) #hovering over any of the squares or circles for a while will make the tooltip show
        dots.setToolTipDuration(Constants.TOOLTIP_DURATION_MSEC)
        layout.addWidget(dots, Qt.AlignLeft)
        #https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtGui/QPainter.html

    def generateRandomColor(self):
        return '#{0:06x}'.format(random.randint(0, 0xFFFFFF))  # Random color in hexadecimal

class Header(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, date, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.date = date
        self.initUI()            

    def initUI(self):
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self) 
        TIME_HEADER_OFFSET = "                                               "
        headerString = TIME_HEADER_OFFSET + self.getTimeHeaderString()       
        dateLabel = QLabel(headerString)                  
        layout.addWidget(dateLabel, Qt.AlignLeft)  
        dots = Markers()

    def getTimeHeaderString(self):
        TIME_HEADER_GAPS = "  "
        timeHeader = ["00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00", "04:00", "05:00", "06:00", "07:00", "08:00", "09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:00", "15:00", "16:00", "017:00", "18:00", "19:00", "20:00", "21:00", "22:00", "23:00", "00:00"]
        return "".join(x + TIME_HEADER_GAPS for x in timeHeader) #concatenates all elements in the list

class InfiniteScroll(QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)

        self.content = QWidget()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.content)
        self.layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        self.layout.setSpacing(1)        
        self.setWidget(self.content)

        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.addItem)
        self.timer.start(500)  # Add an item at intervals
        
        date = datetime.datetime.now()
        item2 = Header(date)    
        self.layout.addWidget(item2)

    def addItem(self):
        date = datetime.datetime.now()
        item = OneRowData(date)            
        self.layout.addWidget(item)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    scroll = InfiniteScroll()
    scroll.resize(Constants.MAIN_WINDOW_WIDTH, Constants.MAIN_WINDOW_HEIGHT) #set initial size of the main window
    scroll.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: But this only creates new items at regular intervals. From your initial question (and code) the impression was that items had to be generated on request based on the user scrolling to the bottom.

Comment: The original requirement was "As more data is generated, more rows will be added". It does not depend on the User scrolling. The reason the code is crude is because I have minimal experience with PyQT. I'm working on improving the code whenever I get some time.

Comment: The question was unclear to begin with, as your description had lots of aspects that made it confusing, especially with the example that infinitely added elements *on scroll*. This has nothing to do with language or framework knowledge, the point is to give a succinct and clear explanation of the problem that would not be misleading, without confusing details or unnecessary information.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility, using QScrollArea, is to do something similar to what Qt item views do with models that provide the [`fetchMore()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#fetchMore) capability.

What item views do is to ask the model if more items are available whenever the scroll bar reaches its maximum, which can also happen indirectly (without `valueChanged` signal emission) when the view is resized.

The solution is then to create a similar behavior and eventually add items when required.

The following example shows a basic solution using a custom widget that shows "events" at random times. Note that the event positions use arbitrary values, for a more consistent solution you should use a proper centralized management that considers font metrics and style metrics.

```py
class TimeWidget(QWidget):
    types = 'square', 'circle'
    cache = None
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setMinimumSize(600, 16)
        self.values = []
        for i in range(randint(2, 5)):
            self.values.append((
                randrange(1440), 
                choice(self.types), 
                QColor(randrange(256), randrange(256), randrange(256))
            ))
        self.values.sort(key=lambda i: i[0])

    def event(self, event):
        if event.type() == event.ToolTip:
            pos = event.pos()
            for i, (rect, *args) in enumerate(self.cache):
                if rect.contains(pos):
                    time, shape, color = self.values[i]
                    h, m = divmod(time, 60)
                    text = '{} at {:02}:{}'.format(
                        shape, h, m
                    )
                    QToolTip.showText(
                        event.globalPos(), text, self, rect)
                    break
        return super().event(event)

    def updateCache(self):
        size = max(12, self.height() - 4)
        margin = size // 2
        r = QRect(-margin, (self.height() - size) // 2, size, size)
        self.cache = []
        extent = self.width() - size
        for time, shape, color in self.values:
            x = int(margin + time / 1440 * extent)
            if shape == 'circle':
                func = QPainter.drawEllipse
            else:
                func = QPainter.drawRect
            self.cache.append((
                r.translated(x, 0), color, func
            ))

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        self.updateCache()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if not self.values:
            return
        elif not self.cache:
            self.updateCache()
        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
        for rect, color, func in self.cache:
            qp.setBrush(color)
            func(qp, rect)


class DateSlot(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, date):
        super().__init__()
        self.date = date

        self.timeLabel = QLabel(date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
        self.timeWidget = TimeWidget()

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.timeLabel)
        layout.addWidget(self.timeWidget, stretch=1)


class InfiniteScroll(QScrollArea):
    fetchAmount = 5
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)

        self.content = QWidget()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.content)
        self.layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        self.layout.setSpacing(1)
        
        self.setWidget(self.content)
        self.items = []

        self.verticalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(self.fetchMore)

    def addItem(self):
        if self.items:
            date = self.items[-1].date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        else:
            date = datetime.datetime.now()
        item = DateSlot(date)
        self.items.append(item)
        self.layout.addWidget(item)
        return item

    def fetchMore(self):
        if self.verticalScrollBar().maximum() == self.verticalScrollBar().value():
            if self.items:
                for i in range(self.fetchAmount):
                    self.addItem()
            else:
                baseHeight = self.addItem().sizeHint().height()
                maxHeight = self.viewport().height()
                count = maxHeight // (baseHeight + self.layout.spacing())
                for i in range(count):
                    self.addItem()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        self.fetchMore()

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(640, 480)
```

Another alternative could be using an actual QTableView and a custom model that actually implements `canFetchMore` and `fetchMore`. The benefit of this approach is that you can have headers for dates and times, and then you only need a custom item delegate along with table spanning: in that way, you have only one item for each row, and the delegate will eventually paint "events" at the correct position based on the rectangle assigned to the topleft item (which spans the whole row).

Comment: Your answer looks very rational and you have my upvote. It would be better though if it had the necessary `import` statements and a `main` so I could actually run it...

Comment: I've updated @musicamante's answer with a working example. Now I'll have to try an get the tooltip on mouse hover working and create the functionality to toggle highlighting all widgets of the same color and shape, when any one of them is clicked.

Comment: @Nav please don't edit an answer with a completely different code. If you want to provide an alternative (even if based on similar concepts), then create your own answer. Note that I specifically removed your `wheelEvent()` management because it makes scrolling unintuitive, most importantly because the scroll bar handle becomes inconsistent with the actual scroll, making it difficult to understand when the handle is reaching a specific position.

Comment: @musicamante: Ok. I updated your answer with the code because it was with your idea that I created it. Besides, even Mark had asked for a complete working example. I'll post my code separately. Kindly update your code as a fully runnable example, so it'd help anyone else looking for an answer. My code didn't yet achieve the display of the symbols in a single row, so it was still lacking the finesse required.